# NullReferenceException was unhandled - what is null?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to access an event in my main form by clicking a button (btnsearch_Click) and everytime I clicked it, it says 'object reference not set to an instance of an object'.

Here is my code:

**USER CONTROL**

```
namespace Purchase_Order
{
    public partial class Search : UserControl
    {
        public event EventHandler btnSearchClicked;

        public Search()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void btnsearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

           btnSearchClicked(sender, e);
        }
   }
}
```

**MAIN FORM**

```
namespace Purchase_Order
{
    public partial class formMain : Form
    {

        public formMain()
        {
            InitializeComponent();            
        }




 private void formMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

Search searchbox = new Search();
searchbox.btnSearchClicked += new EventHandler(SearchClicked);
}


 void SearchClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(serverstring);

            try
            {

                string query = "SELECT * FROM tblclassification WHERE INSTR(class_name, @search)";

                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, con);
                MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);

                Search content = new Search();
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@search", content.btnsearch.Text);

                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                da.Fill(dt);


                classification control = new classification();
                control.dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
                control.dataGridView1.DataMember = dt.TableName;

                panelMain.Controls.Clear();
                panelMain.Controls.Add(control);
                MessageBox.Show("OK");

            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                {
                    con.Close();
                }
            }    
        }
```

Comment: Where is `serverstring` initialized?

Comment: can you see on which line the error is thrown using visual studio debugger

Comment: @AntP I'm sorry I forgot to copy the serverstring code, here it is:

string serverstring = "user id = root; password=; server=localhost; database=purchase_order; connection timeout=3;";

Comment: @CodeIgnoto , it is on the line -> btnSearchClicked(sender, e);

Comment: @AntP, is it right that I have put this line of code -> searchbox.btnSearchClicked += new EventHandler(SearchClicked);

in the formMain_Load event?

Comment: @user2083771 Refer to Habib's answer - looks like it's right on the money.

Comment: @AntP I did not understand him, he said that I did not registered the event against it? what did it mean?

Comment: @user2083771 I've added an answer that explains in a little more detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To try and expand a little on Habib's answer (I was going to post this as a comment but it's a little lengthy), you are first creating an instance of `Search` and registering the event in `formMain_Load` here:

```
private void formMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Search searchbox = new Search();
    searchbox.btnSearchClicked += new EventHandler(SearchClicked);
}
```

This is all fine and dandy. However, in `SearchClicked`, you create a **new** instance of `Search` like so:

```
Search content = new Search();
```

This is a **separate** object to the one you created in `formMain_Load` and you never register the event to this object. It looks like what you want to do is share the `Search` instance from `formMain_Load` with the `SearchClicked` method. To do this, create a property in your codebehind:

```
public partial class formMain : Form
{
    private Search _searchbox;
    ...
}
```

Then, in `formMain_Load`:

```
private void formMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _searchbox = new Search();
    _searchbox.btnSearchClicked += new EventHandler(SearchClicked);
}
```

Now, you can reuse this object with the event registered in `SearchClicked` by changing this:

```
Search content = new Search();
```

To this:

```
Search content = _searchbox;
```

You should find that the exception goes away. Hopefully, this will have provided a little more insight and will help you to understand the cause of the error and how to circumvent it.

Comment: I've tried it and it works. Sorry for my non sense question but thank you for still helping me.

Answer (score 4):

You are creating a new instance of your user control in `SearchClicked` method and you are not registering the event against it.

```
Search content = new Search();
```

Also its better if you check whether any control has register your event before raising it like:

```
private void btnsearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 if(btnSearchClicked != null)
       btnSearchClicked(sender, e);
}
```

Comment: I have already registered it in the line -> Search content = new Search(); what do you mean?

Comment: @user2083771, you are not registering the event `btnSearchClicked` with this instance. You can either register the event like `content.btnSearchClicked += new EventHandler(SearchClicked);` or use the usercontrol you created earlier in the form load. Define that at class level and then you can use that in both methods

Comment: Okay, so I added the code `Search content = new Search();
            content.btnSearchClicked += new EventHandler(SearchClicked);` in my main form SearchClicked function, but it displays the same error.

Comment: @user2083771, use a class level object for `Search`, you are creating the instnace inside the event.

Comment: Same error Sir, here is my code, under the class formMain `Search content = new Search();

        void SearchClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
            content.btnSearchClicked += new EventHandler(SearchClicked);
        }`

Comment: @user2083771 I've posted a more in-depth explanation of what Habib is trying to explain as a separate answer - hopefully this will help to break down the problem a little for you.

Answer (score 3):

That means that you haven't got an instance of the type you want to use.

`public event EventHandler btnSearchClicked;` is just a reference for the "real" object you want to use.

It's like you trying to open a door of a house you only have a blueprint. This isn't really possible (at least not in our universe). You will first need to build the house and then try to enter it. Something like this is the case with your problem.

You will have to read a few tutorials about C#

Edit:

The thing about null is that there is nothing the reference you have is pointing too. If you haven't created anything then there isn't anything to reference...

Because you are trying to use something that doesn't exists (is null) you are getting an exception.

Comment: The question is "what is null," not "what does null mean?"

Comment: @AntP The question is a little ambiguous, I don't think he deserves the -1.

Answer (score 0):

Share the Search instance from formMain_Load with the SearchClicked method

**MAIN FORM**

```
 public partial class formMain : Form
    {
        private Search _searchbox;
        ...

private void formMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _searchbox = new Search();
    _searchbox.btnSearchClicked += new EventHandler(SearchClicked);
}

void SearchClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


     Search content = _searchbox;

MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(serverstring);

            try
            {

                string query = "SELECT * FROM tblclassification WHERE INSTR(class_name, @search)";

                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, con);
                MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);


                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@search", content.btnsearch.Text);

                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                da.Fill(dt);


                classification control = new classification();
                control.dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
                control.dataGridView1.DataMember = dt.TableName;

                panelMain.Controls.Clear();
                panelMain.Controls.Add(control);
                MessageBox.Show("OK");

            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                {
                    con.Close();
                }
            }    
            }
        }
```

**USER CONTROL**

```
public partial class Search : UserControl
    {
        public event EventHandler btnSearchClicked;

        public Search()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void btnsearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

           btnSearchClicked(sender, e);
        }
   }
```